# Monkey made my app meow

Tags: android, package, monkey

I ran the exerciser monkey on my app, and for some odd reason, my app meowed!  I have no sound files in my project at all, so I'm a bit confused why a 'meow' sound played.
Any explanations here?

There are also no other projects/files that operate under the package I'm using for this project.

Here is what the terminal states:

```
:Monkey: seed=0 count=1000

:AllowPackage: around.lowell

:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY

// Event percentages:

//   0: 15.0%

//   1: 10.0%

//   2: 15.0%

//   3: 25.0%

//   4: 15.0%

//   5: 2.0%

//   6: 2.0%

//   7: 1.0%

//   8: 15.0%

:Switch: #Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=around.lowell/.Main;end

    // Allowing start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=around.lowell/.Main } in package around.lowell

:Sending Pointer ACTION_MOVE x=-4.0 y=2.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=0.0 y=0.0

    // Allowing start of Intent { cmp=around.lowell/.MainSelect } in package around.lowell

    // Allowing start of Intent { cmp=around.lowell/.EmergencyContactList } in package around.lowell

:Sending Pointer ACTION_DOWN x=207.0 y=282.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=189.0 y=289.0

    // Allowing start of Intent { cmp=around.lowell/.FireDepartment } in package around.lowell

:Sending Pointer ACTION_DOWN x=95.0 y=259.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=95.0 y=259.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_DOWN x=295.0 y=223.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=290.0 y=213.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_MOVE x=-5.0 y=3.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_MOVE x=0.0 y=-5.0

    // Rejecting start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } in package com.android.launcher

:Sending Pointer ACTION_DOWN x=74.0 y=201.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=74.0 y=201.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_MOVE x=3.0 y=-2.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=0.0 y=0.0

    // Rejecting start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL 
dat=tel:978cmp=com.android.contacts/.DialtactsActivity } in package com.android.contacts

:Sending Pointer ACTION_MOVE x=-4.0 y=2.0

    //[calendar_time:2011-08-16 11:00:43.937  system_uptime:589497185]

    // Sending event #100

:Sending Pointer ACTION_UP x=14.0 y=35.0

:Sending Pointer ACTION_DOWN x=129.0 y=13.0

Events injected: 1000

:Dropped: keys=0 pointers=15 trackballs=0 flips=0

 Network stats: elapsed time=36844ms (0ms mobile, 36844ms wifi, 0ms not connected)
// Monkey finished
```

That is only some of the events - when I pasted all 1000 events, it took this page a while to load, so I only posted at least one of the variety of events that had occurred.

Comment: If you showed your replication source code it would get you more help

Comment: Upvoted for funny title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've noticed that the monkey sometimes starts playing audio files on your sd card independent of the package you specify

Comment: So essentially, it's not my app that has this sound hidden somewhere deep within it?  Thank you for your response!